# How do you pass Cognito user pool groups to Lambda context with API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have several Lambda functions behind an API Gateway that is using Lambda Proxy integration. Each function is configured with the AWS_IAM authorizer. I am able to successfully authenticate against a Cognito User Pool and then retrieve the user's ID from the Lambda event like described here https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/mapping-cognito-identity-id-and-user-pool-id.html.

However I am struggling to get the list of User Pool groups that the authenticated user belongs to. Ideally they would be passed as part of the event since the Cognito authorizer would already have this info. I have seen mentions of adding mappings to the method's Integration Request but that doesn't seem to be an option when using Lambda Proxy integration.

I have also tried all the recommendations here with no luck. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/390

Comment: is this what you're looking for ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44780052/290036

Comment: @HoratiuJeflea I had tried that but always got null from `userPool.getCurrentUser()`. I also don't see a JWT token in the Lambda. I do see them on the client side but that payload already has the groups listed.

Answer (score 5):

I can't believe they just don't pass this in.  Here's what I did:

#### 1. Modify the `serverless.yaml` to get permissions:

```
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - cognito-idp:AdminListGroupsForUser
      Resource: ${self:custom.userPoolArn}
```

That lets my lambda functions access the AdminListGroupsForUser function.

#### 2. Get Cognito group in the lambda function

Use the string parsing function you [referenced here](https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/mapping-cognito-identity-id-and-user-pool-id.html) you can get the UserPoolUserId and the UserPoolId. My lambda code is in python but its the same idea:

```
auth_provider = event['requestContext']['identity']['cognitoAuthenticationProvider']
userPoolUserId = parts[-1] # the last part of the list
userPoolId = parts[0].split('/')[-1]
```

Then with those values you pass to the `AdminListGroupsForUser` that you gave permissions to in the previous step.

```
cognito = boto3.client('cognito-idp')
groups = cognito.admin_list_groups_for_user(
            UserPoolId = userPoolId,
            Username = userPoolUserId
            )
print(groups)
```

You'll then get a hash with all the groups they belong to.  If there are a bunch of groups you can pass other parameters to `AdminListGroupsForUser` to get them.  Hope that works for you!

Comment: I've made a couple attempts at this. My latest one is timing out while trying to call adminListGroupsForUser. From what I've found so far it is most likely because my lambda is in a private VPC. However I've tried opening up the security group egress rules and even removing the lambda from the private VPC with no luck.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  The error I get if I don't have permissions basically says 'Not authorized to call AdminListGroupsForUser'.  So if its timing out that could be network related (private VPC like you say).  I don't have any egress rules as I'm not on private VPC with the function.