# Token and cookie session id security

Tags: security, authentication, jwt, xss, session-cookies

I think I understand the difference between tokens and session ids.

But it seems to me that it has a major security issue so I've probably misunderstood something :

If **someone steals** my token or my session id then **he can pretend to be me**, right? Some XSS attack, or some F12 on my friend's computer is enough to see the info, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's why you wouldn't leave your device unattended to take care of the F12 part.

XSS cannot steal `httpOnly` cookie.

I've covered mist of these in the following two answers.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54258744/1235935

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59464645/1235935